# how to resolve The content of element type "application" is incomplete, it must match "(icon?,display-name,description?,module+,security-role*)".?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ear

i am getting the below error in the console when i'm trying to run my application on glassfish.

```
SEVERE: DPL8015: Invalid Deployment Descriptors in Deployment descriptor file META-INF/application.xml in archive
    " The content of element type "application" is incomplete, it must match "(icon?,display-name,description?,module+,security-role*)".
```

i have the following code in my "application.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE application PUBLIC
    "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD J2EE Application 1.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/application_1_3.dtd">
<application>
  <display-name>MTCpreprint</display-name>
</application>
```

What should be done to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this part of the error message:

> `it must match "(icon?,display-name,description?,module+,security-role*)"`

I would suggest that a `<module>...</module>` element is a required part of your XML. At least one such element must be present.

- `?` – indicates optional
- `+` – indicates one or more
- `*` – indicates zero or more

Comment: So should i add module, security-role elements to the xml?.

Comment: @Newbee `<security-role>` appears to be optional (e.g. *zero* or more). So whether you include that will depend upon your deployment needs.

Comment: @Newbee Please bear in mind I'm not an expert in this area, so my advice is just an interpretation of the error message. I think my interpretation is correct, but please observe the other answers to this question.

Answer (score 3):

The layout of your `application.xml` is wrong: It has to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  version="6" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd">

   <application-name>MTCpreprint</application-name>
</application>
```

If the file is automatically generated at every build you'll have to diable this. If you are using the `maven-ear-plugin` you can disable the auto-generating of `application.xml` like this:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8</version>
        <configuration>
            <generateApplicationXml>false</generateApplicationXml>
        </configuration>                
    </plugin>
```

Comment: As you know the application.xml file is generated every time i build my application. What changes should i make to generate the app.xml in the correct format?

Comment: Thanks unwichtich, i will try this and let you know.

Comment: This did not work for me.  As @Duncan said, the module needs to be defined.